# Django Multi join query

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I am new to django and need to do a query. I can do in sql but I can't seem to figure it out in django. Here it is in SQL. Can someone tell me how to do it in django.

```
select token from api_userprofile
join api_userdevice on api_userdevice.user_id=api_userprofile.user_id
join api_device on api_device.id=api_userdevice.device_id
where api_device.serial=3
```

My models look like this:

```
class UserDevice(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
   device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
   activation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=False)
   friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
   is_owner = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
   is_admin = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)

class Device(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=False, unique=True)
    publickey = models.CharField(max_length=44, null=False)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    token = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correctly, you can try:

```
users_pks = UserDevice.objects.filter(device__serial=3).values_list('user__pk')
qs = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__pk__in=users_pks).values('token')
```

for check sql query, you can print:

```
print (qs.query)
```

Comment: It it is giving me an AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'values__list' error. Is what I am trying to do is return all the tokens for users that share a device__serial number

Comment: sorry for typo! glad to help you)